# How to center the y-axis label horizontally in Highcharts?

Tags: label, highcharts, axis

I have set the y-axis label to "align: high", that is it appears on top of the y-axis, horizontally. Now, as my title goes on two lines, I'd like to center the y-axis label. I tried it with "yaxis: { title { style { text-align: center}}}" and tried as well to put some CSS into the title. But it doesn't work.

Has anyone a tip for me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You mean title of chart or yAxis ?

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.title.align
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#title.align

Comment: I mean yAxis title. But the "center" is not for "horizontally centered", but only "vertical centered".

Comment: got any answer to this?

Comment: Hmmm... Don't remember anymore. Perhaps I went with changing the X values in the "yAxis > title". Check out the graphs I produced, perhaps they can help you: http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/megatrends/sammlung_alle.php

Comment: You can also try to set useHTML, width of title (style parameter) http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.title.style and try set CSS styles..