# How to center the yAxis title in Highcharts

Tags: css, highcharts, axis

Is there any way to center the yAxis title, when it's displayed on top of the yAxis in Highcharts? This is a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767504/how-to-center-the-y-axis-label-horizontally-in-highcharts); haven't found a solution yet.

This is how it looks like in the moment:

[image]

```
yAxis: {
  title: {
    text: "Cumulative mean<br />annual mass balance<br />(mm w.e.)",
    align: "high",
    rotation: 0,
    x: 180,
    y: -30,
    useHTML: true,
    style: {
      align: "center",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }
  },
```

I'd like to have these three centered. Tried it with useHTML and align. But doesn't work...

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/vXhDC/183/).

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: change x value from 180 to 100 or else

Comment: In case the title should be aligned in center, you can use [subtitle](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#subtitle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in CSS.

To horizontally center the y-axis, add these styles, and remove the x value:

```
.highcharts-axis {
  position: relative;
  left: 50% !important;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

To center-align its text, use this style:

```
.highcharts-axis {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/domw91pf/)

Comment: Just for completeness for this post: The Highcharts code should integrate the useHTML tag: `yAxis: { title: { useHTML: true}}`